# WSE 2.0 Web Services Client using .NET 2.0

Tags: web-services, .net-2.0, wse2.0

What's the best way to access WSE 2.0 web services from .NET 2.0?
Using VS2005's web references is not working, because generated classes are using System.Web.Services as their base (instead of Microsoft.Web.Services2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use VS2003 to generate and update the web references with a batch file to copy them to the vs2005 and now 2008 project.

Comment: It is best to do this using WSE 2.0 SP3. Apparently the generated code with SP3 is (or at least was) supported by MS with .NET 2.0.